# Find/Filter function in angular typescript throws an error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to find a record by id using angular typescript, this is my array given below

```
     {
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "1731002618",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "rating": 3,
      "price1": 34.00,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "price2": 1.97,
      "cuom2": "sq. ft.",
      "saving": 22,
      "was": 41.48,
      "addToCart": "addToCart",
      "badges": [
        "badge-ECO",
        "badge-NLP",
        "badge-SB",
        "badge-ES"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1911002437",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "price1": 34.00,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "promo": "+25% Off Select Products",
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    },
    {
      "id": "1661232636",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "price1": 41.48,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "price2": 2.40,
      "cuom2": "sq. ft.",
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    },
    {
      "id": "1231002635",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "rating": 4,
      "price1": 41.48,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    },
    {
      "id": "1561002634",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "rating": 4,
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    },
    {
      "id": "1781002633",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "price1": 41.48,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    },
    {
      "id": "1121002632",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "price1": 41.48,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "addToCart": "addToCart"
    },
    {
      "id": "1461002631",
      "imageUrl": "product_1.jpg",
      "brand": "Max Home Collection",
      "title": "5.2 cu. ft. High-Efficiency Stackable Front-Load Washer in White",
      "model": "7L12X165/8045CL",
      "price1": 41.48,
      "cuom1": "case",
      "addToCart": "viewDetails"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am doing something like this

```js
getProductByID(postid:string):Product {
    this.http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl).subscribe(data => {
             this.product=data;    
    });
    
    // return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl);
    return { ...this.product.find(p=>p.id===postid) };
}
```

```
ngOnInit() { 
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap)=>{ 
    if(paramMap.has("postid")) { 
        alert('differentiate '+paramMap.get("postid"));
        alert('before call');
        var p = this.Service.getProductByID(paramMap.get("postid"))
                           .subscribe(data=>{ console.log(data);});
    }) 

}
```

it says error in find function, I tried filter function as well, but still the same,
your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? But a first look at your method shows that you're not returning an observable of array

Comment: let me modify that hang on

Comment: I just modified that and want to return a single record, still no luck

Comment: Where are you using the method getProductByID ?

Comment: from component, I am fetching the product by id

Comment: I can't help you without knowing where you use getProductByID method.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap)=>{
        if(paramMap.has("postid"))
        {
            alert('differentiate '+paramMap.get("postid"));
          
           alert('before call');
           var p= this.Service.getProductByID(paramMap.get("postid")).subscribe(data=>{
               console.log(data);
           });
           
    })
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subscribe in your service!

Your `getProductsByID()` method should define the http call and the data transformation needed to return the desired shape.  You should return an observable and let consumers of the service subscribe to it.

The `.pipe()` method allows you to transform the values that come through the stream by using the various operators.  In this case, you can use the `map()` operator to map the incoming array of products to a single product (or undefined if the product doesn't exist).

service:

```
// Returns an observable stream that emits a single
// product (after receiving the entire product
// list and filtering down to one by postid)

getProductByID(postid:string):Observable<Product|undefined> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl).pipe(
        map(products => products.find(p => p.id === postid))
    );
}
```

Depending on what you need to do in your component, you may not even need to subscribe there, if you leverage the [async pipe](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/a) in your template.  Let's define a couple different observables$, so it's easier to see what's going on.

We can use [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params) to get the params as an observable source.

component:

```
postid$: Observable<string>;
product$: Observable<Product>;

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // Stream that emits the latest value of postid.
    // Doesn't emit if the value is null/undefined.

    postid$ = route.params.pipe(
        map(p => p.postid),
        filter(p => !!p)
    );


    // Stream that emits the latest value of product. Takes 
    // value of postid$ and uses it to make http call.

    product$ = postid$.pipe(
        switchMap(postid => this.Service.getProductByID(postid)),
        tap(product => console.log('product:', product))
    ); 
}
```

You can use the `tap` operator to perform side-effect type things or just log to console.

In your template:

```
<div *ngIf="product$ | async as product">
   <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
   <p>Model:{{ product.model }}</p>
   <p>Price:{{ product.price }}</p>
   <img src="{{ product.imageUrl }}">
</div>
```

The async pipe is nice because it will automatically subscribe/unsubscribe for you.

Answer (score 1):

Observables can be converted to promises using [toPromise()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise):

### Component

```js
ngOnInit() { 
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap)=>{ 
    if(paramMap.has("postid")) { 
        alert('differentiate '+paramMap.get("postid"));
        alert('before call');
        const product = await this.Service.getProductByID(paramMap.get("postid"));
        console.log('product is',product);
    }) 

}
```

### The service

```
async getProductByID(postid:string):Promise<Product>
   {
        const products = await this.http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl).toPromise();

        return products.find(product=>product.id===postid);
   }
```

Comment: Type 'Observable<Product[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product>'.
  Type 'Product[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': id, imageUrl, brand, title, and 2 more.ts(2322)

Comment: You forgot to use `await` or `.then` after defining `product` in `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run find on `this.product` before its set.  Observables are asynchronous, so your return will happen before `this.product=data` runs.

You will need to return it as an observable, and subscribe somewhere else

```js
getProductByID(postid:string):Observable<Product> { // Not actually sure if this is returning a product or not, its an Observable of something...
   this.http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl)pipe(map(data => {
       this.product=data; 
       return { ...this.product.find(p=>p.id===postid) };
   })
  );
   
}

// Then when you need to call this method...
this.getProductByID('someId').subscribe(data => {
   // this will be `{ ...this.product.find(p=>p.id===postid) };` 
  console.log(data);
})
```